# Creating a map of string and function, which takes parametrised types

Tags: generics, java-8

I want to create an map of (key, function) so that I can get right function a particular key,where 'key' is string. That function takes map of (key, value) , both of which are strings, return back a result of type ExtractedParam.

Here is the ExtractedParam class

```
class ExtractedParams<T> {
String key;
Optional<T> value;
String errorMessage;

public ExtractedParams(String key, Optional<T> value, String message) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.errorMessage = message;
}

public Optional<T> getValue() { return  value;}
}
```

Here is the class with main methods and functions

```
public class Spike {
private static Function< Map<String,String>, ExtractedParams<String> > typeExtractor = (m) -> {
    if (!m.containsKey("type")) {
        return new ExtractedParams<>("type", Optional.empty(), "type is a mandatory parameter");
    }
    String dt = m.get("type");
    return new ExtractedParams<>("type", Optional.of(dt), null);
};

private static Function< Map<String,String>, ExtractedParams<Integer> > valueExtractor = (m) -> {
    if (!m.containsKey("v")) {
        return new ExtractedParams<>("v", Optional.empty(), "v is a mandatory parameter");
    }
    Integer v = 0;
    try {
        v = Integer.parseInt(m.get("v"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return new ExtractedParams<>("v", Optional.<Integer>empty(), "v is a number");
    }
    return new ExtractedParams<>("v", Optional.of(v), null);
};

private static Map<String, Function<Map<String, String>, ExtractedParams<? extends Object> > > paramFunctionMapper = new HashMap();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    paramFunctionMapper.put("type", typeExtractor);   // compiler error
    paramFunctionMapper.put("value", valueExtractor); // compiler error                                                                               }
}
```

}

As you can see I am trying to add a particular function for a key to a hash map. But compiler flags it as an error says that 2nd argument for 'put' method is not of type ', ExtractedParams' but ', ExtractedParams' (in case of first put)

I always thought having ExtractedParams should allow ExtractedParams or ExtractedParams.

What is wrong is here? Please help me understand.

(UPDATE) using the ExtractParams class above the following compiles

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map< String, ExtractedParams<? extends Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("type",new ExtractedParams<String>("dt", Optional.of("number"), ""));
    map.put("value",new ExtractedParams<Integer>("value", Optional.of(4), ""));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `E<String>` is a subclass of `E<? extends Object>`, `F<E<String>>` is NOT a subclass of `F<E<? extends Object>>`.

Just as you had to do `E<? extends Object>` to make it a super class of `E<String>`, so you have to do `F<? extends E<? extends Object>>`.

If you declare your map as `Map<String, Function<Map<String, String>, ? extends ExtractedParams<? extends Object>>>`, it will compile .

Alternatively, you can declare your functions with a wildcard:

```
private static Function< Map<String, String>, ExtractedParams<?>> valueExtractor = ....
```

And, perhaps the most readable approach is to declare your extractors as methods and then use a method reference:

```
static ExtractedParams<String> getType(Map<String, String> m) {
     .....
}

Map<String, Function<Map<String, String>, ExtractedParams<?>>> mapper = new HashMap<>();

mapper.put("type", Spike::getType);
```